# Svelte child component checkbox does not reflect props

Tags: svelte, carbon-components-svelte

I've come unstuck while building my first Svelte project. I've built a tree-view component in which each node has a checkbox; checkbox-change values should be passed down to the child nodes.

My tree-view consists of two components (`TreeNode` is a class which contains, for example the text which should appear on each node):

```html
<!-- TreeView.svelte -->
<script lang="ts">
    import TreeNode from "./TreeNode";
    import TreeNodeView from "./TreeNodeView.svelte";

    export let isChecked: boolean = false;
    export let treeNodes: Array<TreeNode>;
</script>

<ul role="group">
    {#each treeNodes as treeNode ( treeNode.id )}
        <TreeNodeView {isChecked} {treeNode} />
    {/each}
</ul>
```

```html
<!-- TreeNodeView.svelte -->
<script lang="ts">
  import ...

  let hasFocus: boolean = false;

  function onChecked(e: CustomEvent<boolean>) {
    isChecked = e.detail;
  }

  export let isChecked: boolean;
  export let treeNode: TreeNode;

  $:{
    console.log(`${treeNode.text}.isChecked = ${isChecked}`);
  }
</script>

<li>
    </div>
  {:else}
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
  {/if}
  {#if treeNode.children.length === 0}
    <Link href="~"><Checkbox labelText={treeNode.text} /></Link>
  {:else}
    <Checkbox checked={isChecked} labelText={treeNode.text} id={treeNode.id} name={treeNode.id} on:check={onChecked} />
  {/if}
  {#if treeNode.isSelected && treeNode.children.length}
    <TreeView treeNodes={treeNode.children} {isChecked} />
  {/if}
</li>
```

In the reactive block (`$: { ... }`) it appears that the `isChecked` value *is* being passed down, but none of the checkboxes reflect the updated value. *I.e.*, when checking `de-CH` in the following node...

[image]

I see this in the console...

[image]

... but the two child-node checkboxes remain stubbornly unchecked.

What have I missed?

[The styled components I'm using are carbon-components-svelte.]

**UPDATE:**
I realised that I had omitted the `checked` binding in one of the checkboxes: In my TreeNodeView.svelte component I needed to add...

```
{#if treeNode.children.length === 0}
  <Link href="~">
    <Checkbox labelText={treeNode.text} checked={isChecked} /> // << checked={isChecked}
  </Link>
{:else}
  // ...
{/if}
```

What a silly mistake - sorry to anyone who gave this any thought.

Comment: I think, if possible to add key in the checkbox like ```<Checkbox bind:checked={isChecked} labelText={treeNode.text} id={treeNode.id} name={treeNode.id} on:check={onChecked} key={isChecked} />```. This will add attribute to the Checkbox component that changes whenever ```isChecked``` changes, forcing Svelte to recreate the component and update the checkbox's checked state. Just guess..

Comment: `key` is not recognised by the `Chekbox` component (which is from Carbon Components). _Object literal may only specify known properties, and '"key"' does not exist in type 'CheckboxProps'._

Comment: If so, allow me to post an answer to give a more and detailed explaination. If isn't solve your problem or not very useful, please inform me so I will remove it.

Answer (score 1):

If the change is not being reflected in the UI, it could be due to the way the checkbox component is handling its `checked` prop. If the checkbox component is not properly reacting to changes in it's `checked` prop, it might not update its internal state or the DOM correctly, even though the prop itself is being updated.

This way is to ensure that the checkbox component updates correctly when it's `checked` prop changes. It is the use of **two-way binding**. You can use the `bind:checked` directive to create a two-way binding between the `checked` prop and the checkbox's internal state. This means that changes to the checkbox's state will update the `checked` prop, and changes to the `checked` prop will update the checkbox's state.

Example two-way binding for this;

```
<Checkbox bind:checked={isChecked} labelText={treeNode.text} id={treeNode.id} name={treeNode.id} on:check={onChecked} />
```

This should ensure that the checkbox's state is updated whenever the `isChecked` prop changes, and vice versa.

If still problem with the above, It could be that the checkbox component is not properly handling the `on:check` event. You could try using Svelte's built-in `on:change` event instead, which is triggered whenever the checkbox's state changes. You could then update the `isChecked` prop in the event handler.

Example;

```
<Checkbox checked={isChecked} labelText={treeNode.text} id={treeNode.id} name={treeNode.id} on:change={e => isChecked = e.target.checked} />
```

This will ensure that the `isChecked` prop is updated whenever the checkbox's state changes, which should cause the component to re-render with the updated state.

## Edit (As additional issue found.)

In your `TreeNodeView.svelte` component, you're using a `CustomEvent` to update the `isChecked` value. However, this event is only being listened to in the `TreeNodeView` component itself, and not being passed up to the parent `TreeView` component or any child components. This means that when you check a box, the `isChecked` value is updated in the `TreeNodeView` component, but this change isn't reflected in the parent or child components.

If so, you'll need to dispatch an event from the `TreeNodeView` component whenever the checkbox is clicked, and listen for this event in the parent `TreeView` component. When the event is fired, the parent component should update the `isChecked` value for the corresponding `TreeNode` and pass this new value down to the child components.

In `TreeNodeView.svelte`, dispatch an event, so whenever a checkbox is clicked, the `isChecked` value should be updated in the parent `TreeView` component and passed down to the child components, updating the state of the checkboxes accordingly.

```
<script lang="ts">
 // ...

 function handleCheck(e: CustomEvent<boolean>, treeNode: TreeNode) {
   treeNode.isChecked = e.detail;
 }

 // ...
</script>

<ul role="group">
   {#each treeNodes as treeNode ( treeNode.id )}
       <TreeNodeView {isChecked} {treeNode} on:check={(e) => handleCheck(e, treeNode)} />
   {/each}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but I've realised that I had made a silly mistake. I've updated original post to point out what I had missed.

Comment: I edit the answer.